# Must a Developable Surface be Tangent Developable or a Generalised Cone/Cylinder?

Tags: differential-geometry

I've commonly seen that  tangent developable surfaces, Generalised cones and generalised cylinders are developable surfaces. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface)

But are these the only possible generalised surfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Developable surfaces are surfaces with zero Gaussian curvature. Since there exist formulas for the Gaussian curvature in terms of a particular parametrization, the equation $K=0$ is a non linear differential equation which in general is untractable. As you pointed out cylinders and cones satisfy the equation $K=0$ as well as planes. Other classes of surfaces can be developable. This is for instance the case of non cylindrical ruled surfaces when the condition $(\overrightarrow{\alpha}^{'} \times\overrightarrow{w}) \cdot \overrightarrow{w}^{'}=0$, where the curve $\overrightarrow{\alpha}(t)$ is the directrix of the surface, while $\overrightarrow{w}(t)$ is the vector giving the direction. A general developable surface is in some sense the union of tangent developables. In other word a developable surface is the union of cylinders, cones, and tangent developables.

Comment: What sort of "union"? Is it some sort of surgery on manifolds? If so what are the boundaries?

Comment: Union of patches. Any regular orientable surface M can be covered by a family of regular injective patches such that any two patches $a:D\rightarrow M$ and $b:D\rightarrow M$ with $a(D) \bigcap b(D) \neq 0$ are coherently oriented.